# Limit Characters returned in Header within Postman Environment

Tags: java, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm working with an API set that requires a Session Key to be pulled down and used in the Authorization Header for subsequent calls to the service. The value to be added to the Header is **X-CardConnect-SessionKey** See below for example. The first 20-digits, everything in front of the semi-colon, needs to be included in future calls to the service once obtained.

[image: Postman Image]

This is what I'm getting -->

```
X-CardConnect-SessionKey →9ffcd7dc737f4b9fbdccb299b9c55f4b;expires=2017-12-28T20:54:19.652Z
```

This is what I need:

```
X-CardConnect-SessionKey →9ffcd7dc737f4b9fbdccb299b9c55f4b
```

In Postman I am using the following to parse the Session Key value into my environment:

```
var data = responseHeaders
postman.setEnvironmentVariable ("X-CardConnect-SessionKey", data["X-
CardConnect-SessionKey"])
```

Naturally, the full string is inserted into the Environment when I only need the first 20 digits. Is there a way to limit the character limit so that only the first 20 digits are returned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the value using native JS or look at using one of the Lodash [_.split()](https://lodash.com/docs/#split) functions.

```
var data = "9ffcd7dc737f4b9fbdccb299b9c55f4b;expires=2017-12-
28T20:54:19.652Z"

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("test", data.split(';',1));
```

Or for what you need something along these lines:

```
var data = responseHeaders
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("X-CardConnect-SessionKey", data.X-
CardConnect-SessionKey.split(';',1))
```

Comment: Ty Danny. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @RobertCowie try that out to see if it works for what you need

Comment: Not had a chance to test it out, from memory so it might not work first time.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve with the following:

```
const data = responseHeaders;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable ("X-CardConnect-SessionKey", data["X-CardConnect-SessionKey"]); 
const sessionheader = data["X-CardConnect-SessionKey"];
postman.setEnvironmentVariable ("X-CardConnect-SessionKey",  sessionheader.substring(0, 32));
```

Comment: Cool, do you need to create all the variables? You could probably do all that in one line. Check out the `pm.response.headers()` in the [`pm.*`](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) api that’s part of the newer versions. The syntax you’re using is in the older style and will be dropped soon.